A rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes is drawn inscribed in the ellipse : $b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2$. Find its area
A rectangle (with sides parallel to the coordinate axes) is drawn inscribed in the ellipse $b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2$. I want to find its area.
I have been told that since $b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2$, it follows that $x^2=\frac{a^2 b^2}{a^2+b^2}$ and therefore that $4x^2=4\frac{a^2 b^2}{a^2+b^2}$.
Ie $(2x)^2=4\frac{a^2 b^2}{a^2+b^2}$. I don't understand why the area of this rectangle is $(2x)^2$ though. I also don't understand why this is the area of any rectangle here.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

I've just introduced MathJax in the title of your question. Now you use such MathJax in order to formulate your question and you might have a chance someone looking at your question.

You will have an infinity of acceptable rectangles. You can identify them by the value of $x\in[0; a]$ (and then $y = \frac b a \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$), or by the value of $\theta\in[0;\frac\pi 2]$, with $x=a\cos(\theta)$ and $y=b\sin(\theta)$...

From @SergeBallesta 's comment, we can get the area to be $$|4ab\cos\theta\sin\theta|=|2ab\sin 2\theta|$$

This is not an answer, but it's impossible to add a drawing to a comment.
When looking at the following drawing, you can easily see that the surfaces of the green and the purple rectangles are different.
So why are you looking for the mentioned formula if different values are possible?
Image:


Your question has many possibilities for framing rectangles... with big areas and small areas... inside an ellipse.

( While learning calculus later you would find a $45^{0}$ cutting line gives an inside square of maximum area. )
